# Explicit computation of the first Chern class of a quintic three-fold

Tags: complex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, characteristic-classes, kahler-manifolds

I have a question concerning a computation of the first Chern class of a quintic three-fold $X \subseteq \mathbb{CP}^4$. It is claimed that $X$ is Calabi--Yau, so $c_1(X) =0$. Can someone provide an explicit computation showing this?

Comment: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~auroux/18.969-S09/mirrorsymm-lect6.pdf

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you very much